# button default selection issue when activity load

Tags: android, button, android-activity

**

> I have two activities in my app. when a homepage button is clicked,
>   second activity starts normally. In second activity there are three
>   buttons:-button 1,button 2,button 3.So I want that when a second
>   activity starts, button 1 is automatically active and display that
>   work.

**

Comment: what do you mean by activating button 1.Make it visible and hide 2 other buttons ?

Comment: use performClick(); on button object will fire click event of button

Comment: If you want to automatically click on a button then use code `button1.performClick();`

Comment: when activity load i just want one button must be selected and want to change its background with pink. rest of two button must be unselected with white background

Comment: let us know how much you tried - post the code.

Answer (score 0):

**First Step:** Make a button selector xml named it as "button_selector.xml", so that it would show active when opening second activity

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape  android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/button_active_color" />
        </shape></item>

    <item android:state_focused="true"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/button_active_color" />
        </shape></item>

    <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/button_inactive_color" />
        </shape></item>
</selector>
```

**Second Step:** In Second Activity button 1 click listener set button selector which we have defined above

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_selector);
            }
        });
```

**Third Step:(for making button active)** In Second activity `onCreate()` method after initialising button1 by `findViewById()` call it as

```
  button1.performClick();
```

Comment: i try button1.performClick(); but still not working .

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable, apply this to your buttons `android:background` make button 1 `android:enabled="false"`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/pink" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>
</selector>
```

In your activity `setOnClickListener()` for all your buttons. Whenever second activity starts run button 1 task.

```
    int lastSelectedViewId;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.setEnabled(false);
        if (lastSelectedViewId != 0)
            findViewById(lastSelectedViewId).setEnabled(true);
        lastSelectedViewId = view.getId();

    }
```

Comment: sorry but i want that when second activity load.at that time button 1 automatically active.and clicked pressed and display that which was in on-click event.

Comment: have you ran the code? it do exactly what you want. first time you have to run default task or use performClick() said by @Clairvoyant. (you need enable button 1 in this case.)